# authentification not working in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel

In RegisterController I wrote

```
$user=User::create([ ... ]); 
Auth::login($user); 
$myid = Auth::id(); 
return redirect()->route('profile',['id'=>$myid]),
```

And I redirect to page with new id.

In web.php I wrote

```
Route::get('/profile/{id}','ProfileController@show')->name('profile');
```

But in `ProfileController` show I wrote `dump(Auth::user())` and it shows 'null' I tried with sessions. But session are not saving and it also shows 'null'. I tried to change Kernel.php but it didnt help. I tried all routes move to middleware web although Laravel automatically uses this middleware. Of course, it also didnt help. I have this problem.

Comment: Please try `dump(Auth::user())`

Comment: i meant Auth::user()        it shows 'null'

Comment: The standard RegisterController already login a new created user. Where did you wrote the code in the controller?

Comment: I didnt make:auth. I did manually authentification. I created RegisterController. I save data in database and redirect to page with new id. but then auth::check() is not working. i created new session in RegisterController and  tried dd(session('example')) in ProfileController. but it shows null. sessions are not saving. therefore auth is not working

Comment: I advise you to start simple: use the standard Auth that ships with laravel and make your modifications, step by step. Without all your code its difficult to guess what is wrong.

Comment: i dont understand why sessions are not saving. i wanted to practise and therefore i decided to do authentification manually. i did it when i watched video. there is working but in my case is not working. ok, i use make:auth

Comment: Can you show your `session.php` config file? Your `.env` file (Redacting your sensitive information) would be beneficial too. Additionally, your `auth.php` config file. Maybe there's something going wrong there

Comment: .env          `APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:Z3s+RyxWLevfxDIiZWuYISF/df15GJXTDe4U0KNDBu0=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://example.com/

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=social_network
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
`

Comment: <?php

`return [

    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),     'lifetime' => 120,

    'expire_on_close' => false,     'encrypt' => false,
    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),    'connection' => null,    'table' => 'sessions',
    'store' => null,
    'lottery' => [2, 100],    'cookie' => 'laravel_session',    'path' => '/',
    'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),    'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),    'http_only' => true,

];

Comment: `'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
 'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],

Comment: 'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],
];`

Answer (score 2):

You should check it like this:

```
dd(Auth::user());
```

Or:

```
dd(auth()->user());
```

And not like this:

```
dump(Auth::user)
```

Comment: i meant Auth::user()        it shows 'null'. I tried dd(auth()->user()); Whole day I try other things(

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the `Auth::attempt($credentials);` method instead of directly calling the Auth::login().

```
Auth::attempt($credentials);
```

will attempt to login the user with the provided credentials building the session and all and will return true if successful and false if fails. So there you can test your outcome straight away.

Check out the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#authenticating-users

You can also specify a guard using `Auth::guard([any-guard])->attempt($credentials)`. In case you don't pass a name to guard() it'd be using the default guard.

Another important thing is that you have to hash your passwords before creating and passing it to a new User. Because all this methods like attempt() will try to match the hashed version of the password. You can hash your passwords like this:

```
Hash::make(<your-password>);
```

Remember to add `use Hash;` in the header of the file or prepend the class name with a backslash like this: `\Hash::make(<your-password>)`

PS: This is only for User creation time. Because `Auth::attempt()` will hash the password automatically. This means you don't have to worryt to hash your password before passing it for authentication.

Comment: In LoginContoller I tried many things `Class LoginController extends Controller
{
 public function log(){
  if (Auth::attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password')])) {
  // $myid=Auth::id();
   // return redirect()->route('profile',['id'=>$myid]);
   echo 'dfgdfgdfgdfg';
  }
  else{
   echo 'no';
  }
  dd(Auth::user());
 }
 
}`                 But its not working. I guess that I have problems with sessions. Sessions are not saving.

Comment: So, what's the output from this code you pasted? Are you getting the "no" echoed? Remember you have to add the `use Auth;` above so it's available in your code.

Comment: Also, another important thing is, did you "hash" the password before saving it to the database? Cause this attempt() method will hash the password field and test with this hashed version. You have to use `Hash::make(<your-password>)` when you pass it to the User::create(). Added this response as part of the answer, as it's useful.

Comment: i get "no". attempt is not working. i wrote use Auth. i also wrote use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth; i tried with bcrypt(password) and without bcrypt. auth is not working.

Comment: Try with `Hash::make()` instead.

Comment: Also remember the password field in your database must be at least 64 chars long. If mysql that is VARCHAR(64) at least.